# Find an equation of the plane perpendicular to vector v and passing through the tip of u

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The given vectors are $v = (3,0,1)$ and $u = (3,1,0)$.

I have used the following formula and plugged in what I have been given using vector $v$ as the variables for $i,j,k$ and vector $u$ for $x_0,y_0,z_0$ and have worked out the solution as follows:
$$3(x-3) - 1(y-1) + 1(z-0) = 0$$
ultimately having $3x - y - 8 = 0$ as the equation of the plane.

Have I understood this correctly?

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The plane perpendicular to $(a,b,c)$ and passing through $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is
$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0\ .$$
For your vectors,
$$3(x-3)+0(y-1)+1(z-0)=0$$
which simplifies to
$$3x+z-9=0\ .$$

Answer (score 7):

Based on David's answer, the concept behind this formula is the following picture:
[image]

Since $\hat{n}$ is orthogonal to the plane, we have $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c \end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}x-x_0\\y-y_0\\z-z_0 \end{bmatrix}=0,$$ then we obtain that formula.

Note that, if $(x_0,y_0,z_0)=(0,0,0)$, then this is a plane (a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$) passing through the origin; if not, this plane is an affine plane (not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ since the plane does not pass through the origin).

Answer (score 0):

$U=(3,1,0),\;V=(3,0,1)$.
Let $P(x,y,z)$ be any point on the plane.
Given the plane passes through $U=(3,1,0)$
$P-U= (x-3,y-1,z-0)$.
As $P-U$ is perpendicular to $V$,
$$(P-U)\cdot V=0,$$ where the dot stands for the scalar product. 
$$(x-3,y-1,z)\cdot(3,0,1)=0\\
\Leftrightarrow 3(x-3)+0(y-1)+z=0\\
\Leftrightarrow 3x+z-9=0$$