# A question regarding perpendicular vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I just read Lang's Introduction to Linear Algebra and I am getting stuck at this part:

[image]

1)What does it mean by "a collection of all points X".

2)In the expression that $(X-P)\cdot N=0$, why does he use $X-P$? Does he mean that the vector $X-P$ is parallel to $ON$, while $ON$ is parallel to $(P+N)$. So the fact that $P+N$ is perpendicular to $P+N$ means $X-P$ is perpendicular to $ON$?

Comment: The plane is the collection of all points in $3$-space that satisfy a particular condition

Comment: 1) The phrase is "**the** collection of all points $X$ (which satisfy some condition)". The indefinite pronoun "a" does not make sense here. 2) The vector $X-P$ realizes the arrow pointing from $P$ to $X$. This is what should be perpendicular to $N$. See the image in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2731654/58818); the point $P$ is given by $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$, the point $X$ by $(x,y,z)$ and the normal $N$ by $n=[a,b,c]$.

Comment: So why does he need to define the vector $X-P$