# How many orthogonal vectors to a given vector

Tags: combinatorics, vector-spaces, vectors, orthogonality

Let's say I have a vector:

$$
v = \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

I was wondering how many vectors would be orthogonal to it. I noticed that these are some of the vectors orthogonal to it.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, 
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Obviously, there are more. Is there a principled way to count the number of orthogonal vectors to a given vector? Thanks!

Comment: What is the field you are working over? The real numbers?

Comment: Assuming this is in $\mathbb{R^3}$, there is an infinite number of vectors orthogonal.

Comment: Yes, real numbers.

Comment: I don't see why the question got downvoted: albeit being quite trivial, it is clearly stated and shows effot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ummm... an infinite number, of course:

[image]

Find a single vector orthogonal to yours, and rotate it by an arbitrary angle around your vector.

And if you also allow vectors of different *magnitude*, well then...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Notice that any vector of the form

$$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ -x-y\end{pmatrix}$$

will be orthogonal to

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

Thus, there is an infinite number of such vectors, more precisely a continuum vectors spanning a two-dimensional subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a plane orthogonal to a vector $(a,b,c)$ passing through $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. This plane is given by the following:

$$
(−0)+(−0)+(−0)=0
$$

For an intuition read this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2731654/775431). Then, since we can have a plane orthogonal to a given vector, and there's an infinite number of vectors living on a plane, we must have an infinite number of vectors orthogonal to a given vector.

Moreover, since we also need to specify a point on which the plane passes to, there are also infinite *orthogonal planes*, each of which have infinite vectors orthogonal to that given vector.